# Adding a vanity light to a switched knob and tube ceiling light

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, knob-and-tube

I shut off the main breaker, disconnected an ancient light fixture, taped new wire to the existing knob and tube and pulled it all up into my attic. Next I pigtailed from the K&T to two new (WBG) wires and ran one to the new vanity light, the other to where the ancient fixture had been. I connected white to white and black to black on the new fixtures. After turning the power back on, only the vanity light lights up. My non contact tester tells me when the switch is off, neither fixture has power and when the switch is on, both fixtures have power.

Aside from not rewiring my entire home, what have I done wrong?

Comment: How did you make the wire connections?

Comment: Post that as an answer with a bit of expansion, and I'll give it a +1, glad you were able to figure it out :)

Answer (score 2):

I rechecked all of the wire nuts and found a wire slipped out of a pigtail. I now can see the light!